# Azure Data lake VS Azure HDInsight

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I was going through the Microsoft documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-overview

I'm new to Azure Data lake and HDInsight. There is a statement in the URL which tells that

```
"Azure Data Lake Store can be accessed from Hadoop (available with HDInsight cluster) using the WebHDFS-compatible REST APIs."
```

As per my initial understanding, Data lake store is a store in which any kind of data can be stored. I think, HDInsight also kind of does the same thing.

My question is what is the difference between Azure Data lake and Azure HDInsight? If HDInsight can be used for file storage or any kind of storage then Why to use Data Lake?It would be great if some one could clarify this in details. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to think of Data Lake is to think of this **large container that has like a real lake with rivers coming into the river** you never know where the rivers are coming from (or what "type" of river). Azure Data Lake was introduced to make big data easy for developers, data scientists, and analysts to store data of any size. **It removes the complexities of ingesting and storing all your data while making it faster to get up and running with big data**. Data Lake is able to stored the **mass different types of data** (Structured data, unstructured data, log files, real-time, images, etc. ) and to blend that together, to correlate many different data types. The key thing here is as we are moving from traditional way to the modern tools (like Hadoop, Cassandra, NoSQL DB, etc). Azure Data Lake includes three services:

- Azure Data Lake Store, a no limits data lake that powers big data
  analytics
- Azure Data Lake Analytics, a massively parallel on-demand
  job service
- **Azure HDInsight**, a full managed Cloud Hadoop and Spark
  offering

[image]

Azure Data Lake Store is like a cloud-based file service or file system that is pretty much unlimited in size. We can run services on top of the data that's in that store. So you could use Hadoop or Spark **in an HDInsight cluster**, or you could use the Azure Data Lake analytic service, which is a complement to the Azure Data Lake Store. And what that service will let you do is to run jobs that effectively query the data you have stored in the Azure Data Lake store and generate output results.

Comment: I am not sure you should draw things this way. Rather, HD Insight and HDP on Azure can use Data Laks Store as can Data Lake Analytics. Excellent otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

In nutshell,

```
Hdinsight is a managed hadoop service (to provide compute support)

Azure Data lake(ADL) is a managed storage service (to provide large amount of storage support)
```

(Instead of ADL, you can alternatively choose to use Blobs in HDinsight, but Blobs have some limitations (like file streaming to storage via hdinsight cluster is not supported)

**Here is the definition from Azure documentation (below):**

Azure uses "decomposed hardware method"

You can relate or assume HDinsight as a Hadoop Cluster, Azure Data lake (ADL) as HDFS. But they are detached.

If you want to relate with AWS, HDInsight is equivalent to EMR and ADL is equivalent to EMRFS or S3

If you terminate the cluster, ADL storage stays with the files stored in it. You can access the storage directly using another service or tool (like Azure Data bricks) or you can create one another hdinsight cluster on top of the data.

> Hdinsight access the ADL using adl:// , and hdinsight never
>   store the file blocks in the nodes (like Hadoop does), rather it has
>   mappings to storage service.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Data Lake Store, is just that a data store.  HDInsight can also do that in the cluster that you spin up.  However, when you stop that cluster, the data also goes away.

It is common that customers use either Azure Data Lake Store, or Azure storage to provide permanent storage separate from the cluster (compute) used to process the data.

Guy

Comment: Are you saying that the data has to be loaded into HDinsight when you do analysis?

Answer (score 4):

HDInsight is the analytics service whereas the Azure Data Lake Storage is the storage service. You most likely need both to have functional analytics cluster.

HDInsight provides the cluster, fully manages the open-source packages for analytics (Hadoop, Spark ...etc), and you set up your cluster to use Azure Data Lake Storage which support HDFS API ( Hadoop FileSystem ) on top of Cloud Storage.

[Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/infopedia/media/channels/kurt-delbene-on-compete) is what you are supposed to start looking at which merges the benefits of both Azure Storage and ADLS in one service.

ADLS Gen 2 documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/data-lake-storage/introduction

Comment: Thanks for the insight (pun semi-intended). The link on Sharepoint doesn't work, might it be internal ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Lake Analytics provides server less compute while using Azure Data Lake Store for data storage, whereas in HDInsight,we need to specify and design for Compute Virtual Machine nodes as per processing requirements. It may be advantageous for developers to work with server less compute in Azure Data Lake Analytics, as scaling needs of Analytics Job are taken care out of box.

Comment: Ahhh, serverless.